# Create a table with 20 random integers and implement the Binary Search algorithm in the table

Tags: python, binary-search

I am trying to create a table with 20 random integers and implement the Binary Search algorithm in the table in python.

Here is my code:

```
def binary_search(a,key):  #function with the binary search algorithm
     imin=0
     imax=le(a)-1
     while (imax >= imin):
         imid=midpoint(imin,imax);
         if (a[imid]==key):
             print(imid)
         elif (a[imid]<key):
             imin=imid+1;
         else:
             imax=imid-1;
     print('KEY_NOT_FOUND')
randomlst=[]                 #a list for saving 20 random numbers
for i in range (20):
    rng=random.randint(1,100)
    randomlst.append(rng)

board=[randolst]             # here i import the list into the board
n=int(input('Give the key')
binary_search(board,n)
```

My questions are:

1. Whether boards in python are like that or not and how can I make a board?
2. How can I add an algorithm into the board?
3. Have I made the binary search algorithm correctly?

Thank you for your time, and excuse my English.

Comment: Did you test your function?  Did it work?  Did yo try it with ```[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]```? What is a `board`?

Comment: File "c:\Python34\askhsh-4b.py", line 29'code'
    binary_search(board,n)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I think you should use https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html module. sorting can be done by `sort`

Comment: The syntax error is because you are missing a final parenthesis in line ```n=int(input('Give the key')```